# Error:"Call to undefined method ping." Using Yii2 and Swiftmailer

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer

Any help would be highly appreciated.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I have used Swiftmailer before and it has never been this difficult to configure it.

I am using an advanced Yii2 project.

This is part of my backend/config/main.php (I have tried with backend/config/main-local.php, common/config/main.php and common/config/main-local.php just in case):

```
....
 'components' => [
 'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'name@example.com',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
                'plugins' => [
                    [
                        'class' => 'Swift_Plugins_ThrottlerPlugin',
                        'constructArgs' => [20],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
....
],
```

This is part of my controller:

```
 public function actionTests()
    {  
    Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom('name@example.com')
            ->setTo('name_2@example.com')
            ->setSubject('Email sent from Yii2-Swiftmailer')
            ->send();
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you getting this error while sending a single email.

Comment: Yes. I am sending one email.