# SwiftMailer Error: Call to a member function ping() on array

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I am trying to send a mail using SwiftMailer. The same thing works on PHP version 7.2, but it throws error on PHP 7.3

[image]

Comment: This issue was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56023790/57091).

Comment: How does your configuration look like? What is the code with which you're trying to send the mail?